# Is there a way to make Wordpress metaboxes tabbed easily in plugin?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, custom-backend

I created a plugin which has a custom post type, and there are tons of metaboxes there that I would like to have more organized or in a tabbed view.

Something like this plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/tabify-edit-screen/

It's really good and quite simple, but I can't implement the view in my plugin.

Is there a premium or free solution for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest Wordpress Admin Style: https://github.com/bueltge/WordPress-Admin-Style

This plugin will allow you to implement a variety of admin styles (including tabs) that you can simply copy and paste directly into your plugin php file.
[image: screenshot of Wordpress Admin Style]

Comment: I think this answered my question.Although I don't know how much work will it take to recode the post metaboxes into this tabbified style.